# PHP SoapVar Object Attribute?

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

Does anyone have any clue as to how I can add an attribute to a SoapVar object? It seems like it would be simple, but I can't get it to take/work.

I've looked at the PHP docs and at the following stackoverflow question:

[Documentation on SoapVar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapvar.php),

stackoverflow question:
[SoapVar/Param and nested, repeated elements in SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855677/soapvar-param-and-nested-repeated-elements-in-soap)

I'm trying to add an attribute like this array example, but using complex SoapVar objects instead.

```
<?php
 $amount['_'] = 25;
 $amount['currencyId'] = 'GBP';
 $encodded = new SoapVar($amount, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

?>
```

and end result wound be

```
<amount currencyId="GBP">25</amount>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I did get a stdClass() object to add the attributes. The request was then a combination of SoapVar Objects and stdClass Objects. Seems to work.

Comment: Please post your solution using stdClass() so others can see how to implement this.

Comment: @jjwdesign, had you posted the solution, it would have saved us a few hours. It took me few hours to figure this out. Final solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971812/php-soapclient-removing-element-with-name/51024996#51024996

Comment: @tarun-lalwani I'm glad you were able to figure out your problem. Nice detailed solution.

Answer (score 1):

Getting attributes into SOAP elements is a bit of a hassle. The way they implemented it is a bit confusing.

First thing to do is add the attributes to the wsdl file that `SoapServer` uses to correctly read and respond to the SOAP requests.

```
<xs:complexType name="encryptionContext">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            **<xs:attribute name="type" type="tns:encryptionType" />**
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

We will have to tell `SoapServer` to use a php helper class by passing it in the options as `classmap`:

```
$soap_server = new \SoapServer($wsdl_file, array(
    'cache_wsdl' => 1,
    'trace' => true,
    'classmap' => array('mediaCollection' => 'SoapMediaHelper')
));
```

What we are mapping here is the SOAP element name `mediaCollection` to one of our classes, `SoapMediaHelper`. Instead of returning arrays, we can now return a `class`, in this case, it's named `SoapMediaHelper`. The class can have soap-element=>value pairs as well as soap-attribute=>value pairs.

Assuming we already have made a class that handles `mediaCollection`s, this tells `SoapServer` to map a class called `SoapMediaHelper` to it. The class is really simple:

```
class SoapMediaHelper
{
    public function __construct(Array $properties = array())
    {
        foreach ($properties as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

The properties of this class have to be populated. These properties should be both the tagname=>value pairs as well as the attribute name and value pair(s) for the attributes we want to add to our `mediaCollection`. `SoapServer` will figure out which is which according to our wsdl file.

We will still have to populate this object, which we can do with yet another class.

```
class SoapVarHelper
{
    public function get($the_playlist, $playlist_id, $owned_by_user){
        /* The SoapMediaHelper class is mapped to the mediaCollection wsdl.
         * This is only needed to be able to set attributes on the XML nodes while using php's SoapServer
         * */
        $media_helper = new SoapMediaHelper($the_playlist);
        /* For this type, the following xml attributes have to be set. (Not in the wsdl example above.) */
        if($playlist_id === 'playlists'){
            $media_helper->readOnly = false;
            $media_helper->userContent = true;
            $media_helper->renameable = false;
            $media_helper->canDeleteItems = true;
            
        }
        if($owned_by_user){
            $media_helper->readOnly = false;
            $media_helper->userContent = false;
            $media_helper->renameable = true;
            $media_helper->canDeleteItems = true;
            $media_helper->canReorderItems = true;
        }
        return new \SoapVar($media_helper, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
    }
}
```

This class should be called with the normal tagname=>value pairs. It then adds the attributes we want. In this case conditionally. We feed our `SoapMediaHelper` object to `SoapVar`. (We told `SoapServer` earlier that this is fine.)

Now the last thing we need to do is, in our `mediaCollection` class, to use the helper `SoapVarHelper` to return a `SoapMediaHelper` (the one we told `SoapServer` about earlier).

In our `mediaCollection` we have a function `get_metadata_for_root`:

```
public function get_metadata_for_root($user_id, $index, $count){
    $titles = array(
        'slides' => 'Featured',
        
    );
    $media_metadata = array();
    foreach($titles as $key => $title){
        $playlist = array(
            'id' => $key,
            'title' => $title,
            'img' => $this->_utils->get_url() . '/public/sonos/images/browse-icons/icon-default-legacy.png'
        );
        **$media_metadata[] = $this->_soap_var_helper->get($playlist, $key, false);**
    }
    $res = array(
        'count' => count($media_metadata),
        'index' => 0,
        'total' => count($media_metadata),
        'mediaCollection' => $media_metadata
    );
}
```

For every `mediaCollection` result we pass it through the `soap_var_helper` to make sure not only the element=>value pairs are added, but also the attributes that we want on it.

TO SUMMARIZE:

1. Make sure you feed the `SoapServer` with a wsdl file, so it know the elements and the attributes.
2. In the `SoapServer` options add `classmap` in order to tell `SoapServer` that it is fine when we feed it a `SoapMediaHelper` object instead of the regular input.
3. Before responding to a request for, in this case, `mediaCollection`, pass this response through the `SoapMediaHelper`. The `SoapVarHelper` will map all the properties=>value pairs as class properties, then the `SoapMediaHelper` will add attributes (also as name=>value pairs) to it.
4. `SoapServer` will take care of the rest.